# Is it possible to upsert using jOOQ-generated record classes?

Tags: java, sql, jooq, upsert

I can perform an `insertInto().onDuplicateKeyUpdate()` if I want to write my insert manually using the DSL, but is there an equivalent on the generated Record class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of jOOQ 3.7, this is not yet possible out of the box. There's a pending feature request for this: [#2961](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2961).

Alternatively, you can write a utility that translates an `UpdatableRecord` into a corresponding `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement. All the meta information needed for this is available from the `UpdatableRecord`:

- [`Record.getTable()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/TableRecord.html#getTable--) to discover the target table
- [`Record.fields()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Record.html#fields--) to discover all the fields in a record
- [`Table.getPrimaryKey()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Table.html#getPrimaryKey--) primary key information, if you need that
- [`Record.changed()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Record.html#changed-org.jooq.Field-) flags to discover the modified values of a record